# two MVC project in one solution with its own views

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have an *administrator MVC* and *front-end MVC*. Admin has *Account-DaimiPanel controller* and codes. Front-end has Home controller.

Front-End project includes Admin in reference. Start-up proect is Fron-end.

**My problem :**

I go `xxx/Home/index =>` no error no problem.

when ı go `xxx/Daimi/Index =>` View not found. Because MVC searchs these views in front-end project . But Admin have theese pages.

so, how fix this ?

note: my english bad. sorry for this.

screenshot;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lT6y.jpg

Comment: Why are you not using Areas? You wouldn't need to have a separate project. The reason the admin cannot see the views because it's in a completely different project and it's a different website.

Comment: I didn't know areas. I firstly coding AdminPanel. I merged projects with copy-paste :) but I spent a lot time for this. Now i want like this. So , what do you advise to me ?

Comment: there are two different web sites, check your urls, you need to address to the correct site. and yes, there is no reason to use two sites for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each MVC project must be run separately to make requests to it, simply adding a reference to the project doesn't *run* it.

You can link from one to the other if both are running, but this is no different than linking between any two given websites. You won't be able to generate URLs for your Admin project from your Frontend project, and vice versa.

If you want them integrated, then they need to be the *same* project. You can use areas to section out the functionality. Otherwise, there's no way to do what you're asking to do.

Comment: What do you mean by Areas ? I see no such option in Solution. Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments.. Areas is the best option..

Right click your solution and add Areas.

1. It will have controllers.. Models and views folders.. You can place your respective codes in these folders.
2. In global.asax register area routes.
3. Now in ur applicaion the urls will work as xxx/area/controller/action

Comment: What do you mean by Areas ? I see no such option in Solution. Where can I find it ?

Comment: when you scaffold project with ASP.NET Web app. The "Areas" folder is in main directory of the web project